# How to get FTP access to my web site?

Tags: web, ftp

I am working in a company and I am improving their web site. Their site is made with WordPress and I have the admin user and the admin password to enter the web as admin and change some files. But I want to change the wp-config.php and this file is not among the files I can change as admin in Word Press. How can I get access FTP accsess to my web site?

Comment: By asking the ftp credentials from the server's administration.

Comment: You need to check with the company how they got their WordPress started up in the first place. Did they get one of those free **WordPress.COM** blogs? Those are limited (really just post something or change a theme and nothing else too clever). You need the full package (**WordPress.ORG**) with FTP access to edit files etc. Check **[difference between WPress.com and WPress.org here](http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/differences-wordpress-com-org/)** or even the **[Official](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)** but the other link explains better than official..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know the URL for accessing your web provider's FTP server. In case you know that, here are the steps:

1. Open up your browser and enter your userid and FTP server name as follows:
   ftp://userid@ftp.yourwebsite.com
2. When prompted, enter your password
3. A list of all the files on your web site will display after a few moments.